# Apk external data, Android Expansion

Tags: android, expansion

I am using concept of Android Expansion which helps us to remove obstacle of 50mb limitation of Apk.

Following all the steps http://developer.android.com/guide/market/expansion-files.html

I understood that you need to follow file format like this `[main|patch].<expansion-version>.<package-name>.obb` and did the same.

And also Expansion files may be in (ZIP, PDF, MP4, etc.) format.

I uploaded additional expansion files while publishing apk on Google play. At the time of download apk I get all the additional in my *Local(Advanced latest Device)*, But through code I am not able to get the expansable files of my application.

In code looking at the sampleDownloader code I came to know that it requires three parameter  `(int type, int expansionCode, long fileSize)`

here `type: main/patch` `expansionCode: integer value` but I am just wondering how to give FileSize in Long(exact)? and second thing its show message like **Download failed because the resource could not be found**

Any idea?

**Update**
Done, all steps are shown **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715855/steps-to-create-apk-expansion-file/11717019#11717019)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you go through [**Downloading the Expansion Files**](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/expansion-files.html#Downloading)? It mentions that

If the expansion files are not there with your Application downloaded from Android Market,
 You have to perform [**Application Licensing**](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/licensing/index.html) to get your app's expansion file **`names`**, `sizes`, and `URLs`.

> 1. Perform a request using Google Play's Application Licensing to get your app's expansion file names, sizes, and URLs.
> 2. Use the URLs provided by Google Play to download the expansion files and save the expansion files.

**UPDATE:**

No, its not compulsory that  Google Licensing only works with paid Application. There is a clear [**Note:**](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/licensing/index.html) defined in the Docs itself that any application may use licensing service to initiate the download of an APK expansion file. But, in that case your request will be only for expansion files and not for a check whether the user paid for the app or not.

Comment: my application is free rite now, I have a query, is Google Licensing works with paid application only?

Comment: I updated my answer. Also this is a seperate question not related to the one that you posted.

Comment: Omg. I am doing right. It is working perfectly on *real Device*. Thanks :)

Comment: Lalit, is it required that the OBB must be uploaded and downloaded to work? Can I simply adb push it to the device and access it in my app for testing purposes?

Comment: @kakyo yes for testing you can put your .obb file inside Android Folder and then inside your app's package name folder.