# Unable to download APK expansion with Google Downloader Sample

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I am trying to get the Downloader Sample to download APK expansion files running. I have carefully gone through the instructions from [Google docs on APK Expansion Files](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/expansion-files.html) and also the very detailed intructions here [Steps to create APK expansion file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715855/steps-to-create-apk-expansion-file/11717019#11717019)

I've

- Changed the sample code to include my BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY
- Uploaded the APK and expansion file to Google Play, and saved the application
- Changed the source code of the sample to reflect the file's size in bytes

Still, when I run the sample on my device I get the message

**Download failed because the resources could not be found**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It suddenly worked and my guess is that the reason was that the changes to the uploaded application needed time to propagate.

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry.. this is Question)
Can we use this Dowloader sample in our App? If used, is there any license related requirements? because every SDK samples are shipped with apache license 2.0