# Accessing to files inside obb expansion file

Tags: android, expansion-files, apk-expansion-files

I'm following all official expansion files guides, but i can't find it. I'm unable to access the contained obb file i need.

I need 6 audio files (80Mb) that i "stored" (uncompressed) in a zip file and renamed as 'main.2001.test.expansion.proj.obb' and stored in '/mnt/sdcard/Android/obb/test.expansion.proj/'

I'll try to access to the files

```
String mainFileName = Helpers.getExpansionAPKFileName(this,true,2001);
if(!Helpers.doesFileExist(this, mainFileName, 27959282L, false))
{
    //download
} else {
    Log.d("test_file","file exist");
}

ZipResourceFile expansionFile = APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile(this,2001,2001);
if(expansionFile!=null)
{
    ZipEntryRO[] ziro = expansionFile.getAllEntries();
    for (ZipEntryRO entry : ziro) {
        Log.d("test_files_zip", "fileZip filename: "+entry.getZipFileName());
        try{
            AssetFileDescriptor ro = entry.getAssetFileDescriptor();
            Log.d("test_files_zip", "--fileZip getfiledescriptor.tostring: "+ro.getFileDescriptor().toString());
            Log.d("test_files_zip", "--fileZip createinputstring.tostring: "+ro.createInputStream().toString());

            AssetFileDescriptor assetFileDescriptor = expansionFile.getAssetFileDescriptor(entry.getZipFileName()+"/audio02.mp3");
            if(assetFileDescriptor!=null) {
                Log.d("test_files_mp3", "length: "+assetFileDescriptor.getLength()); //checking it exists
            }
        }catch (IOException e){ Log.e("test_exp","IoExcp: "+e.getMessage()); }
    }
}
```

In -> assetFileDescriptor = expansionFile.getAssetFileDescriptor(.....); i've tried all i figuret out and found in different places, but i was unable to take the file.
Is there any way to get the file from its name if it's inside the zip?

The app should play these files in an specificorder and we don't want to unzip the files and make them ""public"".

---

Edited. Answer to myself

Found, it was a line i didn't understand when i firstly read it or i simply miss it.

```
ZipResourceFile expansionFile = APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile(this,2001,2001);
if(expansionFile!=null){
        FileDescriptor fd = expansionFile.getAssetFileDescriptor("audio_01.mp3");
        //or
        InputStream is = expansionFile.getInputStream("audio_01.mp3");
    }
```

Comment: may be this asnwer will help you somehow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715855/steps-to-create-apk-expansion-file/11717019#11717019

Comment: No, It's one of the sources i've used, but nothing about reading a file inside the obb.

Comment: I tried `AssetFileDescriptor fd = expansionFile.getAssetFileDescriptor(zip[0].mFileName);`. but `fd` is null. can you help me?

Comment: Did you try with the real file name instead of zip[0].mFileName ?

Comment: If you've answered the question yourself, please add it as an answer below and mark it accepted. This will help future visitors.

Comment: when i used this code it returns an error "Not a zip archive" from ZipResourceFile.class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Aarolama Bluenk suggested, here's the answer code (repited)

Found, it was a line i didn't understand when i firstly read it or i simply miss it.

```
ZipResourceFile expansionFile = APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile(this,2001,2001);
if(expansionFile!=null){
        FileDescriptor fd = expansionFile.getAssetFileDescriptor("audio_01.mp3");
        //or
        InputStream is = expansionFile.getInputStream("audio_01.mp3");
}
```

Comment: ,I am getting an error like "Create class APKExpansionSupport". Do I need to add/download any library. Please help me.