# Reading mp3 from expansion file

Tags: android, file, mp3, expansion

Reading mp3 file from expansion file

I have create and expansion file with name

"main.1.com.example.app.obb"

which contains and audio file name "about_eng.mp3"

Now the issue i have written the following code to read and play the mp3 file

```
    private final static String EXP_PATH = "/Android/obb/";

static String[] getAPKExpansionFiles(Context ctx, int mainVersion, int patchVersion) {
    String packageName = ctx.getPackageName();
    Vector<String> ret = new Vector<String>();
    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        // Build the full path to the app's expansion files
        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File expPath = new File(root.toString() + EXP_PATH + packageName);

        // Check that expansion file path exists
        if (expPath.exists()) {
            if ( mainVersion > 0 ) {
                String strMainPath = expPath + File.separator + "main." +
                        mainVersion + "." + packageName + ".obb";
                File main = new File(strMainPath);
                if ( main.isFile() ) {
                        ret.add(strMainPath);
                }
            }
            if ( patchVersion > 0 ) {
                String strPatchPath = expPath + File.separator + "patch." +
                        mainVersion + "." + packageName + ".obb";
                File main = new File(strPatchPath);
                if ( main.isFile() ) {
                        ret.add(strPatchPath);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    String[] retArray = new String[ret.size()];
    ret.toArray(retArray);
    return retArray;
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get a ZipResourceFile representing a merger of both the main and patch files

    try {
        ZipResourceFile expansionFile = APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile(this,1,1);
        if(expansionFile!=null){

            AssetFileDescriptor fd = expansionFile.getAssetFileDescriptor("about_eng.mp3");
                //or
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource( fd.getFileDescriptor(), 
                    fd.getStartOffset(),fd.getLength());
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();

            }




    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Get an input stream for a known file inside the expansion file ZIPs


}
```

But it is always throwing exception at this line

```
 mediaPlayer.setDataSource( fd.getFileDescriptor(), 
                    fd.getStartOffset(),fd.getLength());
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
```

because the variable fd is null.

Can any body help me to solve this

Comment: I think this post can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635069/accessing-to-files-inside-obb-expansion-file

Comment: Check also if your zip file is not compressed. "getAssetFileDescriptor" return null if the zip is compressed

Comment: Have you solved? I am facing same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495483/read-content-from-apk-expansion-file-from-obb-file

Answer (score 8):

i have googled and found that we shold have to make .zip with `0% (No compression)` that is mention in http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

`Tip: If you're packaging media files into a ZIP, you can use media playback calls on the files with offset and length controls (such as MediaPlayer.setDataSource() and SoundPool.load()) without the need to unpack your ZIP. In order for this to work, you must not perform additional compression on the media files when creating the ZIP packages. For example, when using the zip tool, you should use the -n option to specify the file suffixes that should not be compressed:
zip -n .mp4;.ogg main_expansion media_files`

so **How to make 0% compression zip using winrar?**
[image]

here see the compression method

so we should have to upload this zip in play store.

so you not need to use **ZipHelper.java** that is mentioned in other SO answer

just simply use

```
ZipResourceFile expansionFile=null;

            try {
                expansionFile = APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile(getApplicationContext(),3,0);

                     AssetFileDescriptor fd = expansionFile.getAssetFileDescriptor("test.mp3");
                     MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                     mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                     mPlayer.setDataSource(fd.getFileDescriptor(),fd.getStartOffset(),fd.getLength());
                     mPlayer.prepare();
                     mPlayer.start();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, and don't forget offset and length, otherwise it plays from the first mp3 in the zip file.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `expansionFile.getAssetFileDescriptor("main_expansion/about_eng.mp3")`.

If it doesn't work, call this:

`ZipResourceFile.ZipEntryRO [] entries = expansionFile.getAllEntries();`

and look at the file names:

`entries[0].mFileName;`.

That could be a hint how the path should look like.

I know that the question is old, but maybe it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

To read mp3, with mediaplayer, you can do it 3 ways

for example. my application package name is

> com.bluewindsolution.android.sampleapp

then my expansion file should be

> main.1.com.bluewindsolution.android.sampleapp.obb

in detail, you can followed in [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html)

> [main|patch].< expansion-version >.< package-name >.obb

---

**From expansion you can get it via 3 ways:**

*via AssetFileDescriptor*

```
// this one work with image file, media file
// Get a ZipResourceFile representing a specific expansion file
// mainContext, version no. of your main expansion, version no of your patch
ZipResourceFile expansionFile = APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile(this, 1, 0); 
AssetFileDescriptor afd_img1 = expansionFile.getAssetFileDescriptor("your_path/your_file.jpg");
AssetFileDescriptor afd_mpbg = expansionFile.getAssetFileDescriptor("your_path/your_file.mp3");

// to set image
ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv1); 
imageView1.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(afd_iv1.getFileDescriptor()));

// to set sound
try {
    mpbg.setDataSource(afd_mpbg.getFileDescriptor(), afd_mpbg.getStartOffset(), afd_mpbg.getDeclaredLength());
    mpbg.prepareAsync();
    mpbg.start();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    Log.w("Error=====", "Failed to prepare media player", e);
}
```

---

via InputStream

```
// this one work with image file, media file
// Get a ZipResourceFile representing a specific expansion file

ZipResourceFile expansionFile = new ZipResourceFile(filePathToMyZip);

// Get an input stream for a known file inside the expansion file ZIPs

InputStream fileStream = expansionFile.getInputStream(pathToFileInsideZip);
```

---

*via Uri*

```
//this one can use in almost thing such as jpg, mp3, mp4, pdf, etc.

//you need to create new class to override APEZProvider
public class ZipFileContentProvider extends APEZProvider {
    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return "com.bluewindsolution.android.sampleapp";
    }
}

//you need to add <provider> in AndroidManifest.xml
<provider
 android:name="com.bluewindsolution.android.sampleapp.ZipFileContentProvider"
   android:authorities="com.bluewindsolution.android.sampleapp" 
      android:exported="false"
      android:multiprocess="true"
    >
    <meta-data android:name="mainVersion"
              android:value="1"></meta-data>
</provider>

//after that you can use it any time by this code:
String filename2 = "image/i_commu_a_1_1_1_1.jpg"; // suppose you store put your file in directory in .obb
String uriString2 = "content://com.bluewindsolution.android.sampleapp" +  File.separator + filename2;
Uri uri2 = Uri.parse(uriString2);
imageView2.setImageURI(uri2);

// Filename inside my expansion file
String filename = "video/v_do_1_1_1.mp4"; // suppose you store put your file in directory in .obb
String uriString = "content://com.bw.sample_extension_download_main" +  File.separator + filename;
Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);

v1 = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
v1.setVideoURI(uri);
v1.start();
```