# Read content from APK expansion file (from obb file)

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I have implemented APK expansion file download service and all from http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

I can download APK expansion file and I can see that file using below code

```
try {
        ZipResourceFile expansionFile = APKExpansionSupport
                .getAPKExpansionZipFile(this, 3, 0);

        ZipEntryRO[] zip = expansionFile.getAllEntries();
        Log.e("", "" + zip[0].mFile.getAbsolutePath());
        Log.e("", "" + zip[0].mFileName);
        Log.e("", "" + zip[0].mZipFileName);
        Log.e("", "" + zip[0].mCompressedLength);

        AssetFileDescriptor fd = expansionFile
                .getAssetFileDescriptor(zip[0].mFileName);

        if (fd != null && fd.getFileDescriptor() != null) {
            MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
            mp.setDataSource(fd.getFileDescriptor());
            mp.start();
        } else {
            Log.e("", "fd or fd.getFileDescriptor() is null");
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My obb is having file `test.mp4` and my code `Log.e("", "" + zip[0].mFileName);` prints `test.mp4.`

My `fd` is `null`. Why is it `null`? I am trying to resolve but failed to resolve.

I just can not read any file inside obb file.

Unanswered [Accessing to files inside obb expansion file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635069/accessing-to-files-inside-obb-expansion-file) suggesting idea but it does not work for me.

[Steps to create APK expansion file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715855/steps-to-create-apk-expansion-file/11717019#11717019) tells unzip content from obb and then read it. Is it reliable and good?

I need an opinion on best practice.

### Edit

My log

```
03-01 10:36:40.848: E/(27836): zip[0].isUncompressed() : false
03-01 10:36:40.848: E/(27836): mFile.getAbsolutePath() : /storage/sdcard0/Android/obb/smart.trigger/main.3.smart.trigger.obb
03-01 10:36:40.848: E/(27836): mFileName : test.mp4
03-01 10:36:40.848: E/(27836): mZipFileName : /storage/sdcard0/Android/obb/smart.trigger/main.3.smart.trigger.obb
03-01 10:36:40.848: E/(27836): mCompressedLength : 21657598
```

Answer (score 7):

i have googled and found that we shold have to make .zip with `0% (No compression)` that is mention in http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

`Tip: If you're packaging media files into a ZIP, you can use media playback calls on the files with offset and length controls (such as MediaPlayer.setDataSource() and SoundPool.load()) without the need to unpack your ZIP. In order for this to work, you must not perform additional compression on the media files when creating the ZIP packages. For example, when using the zip tool, you should use the -n option to specify the file suffixes that should not be compressed:
zip -n .mp4;.ogg main_expansion media_files`

OR **How to make 0% compression zip using winrar?**

[image]

here see the compression method

**0% compression zip in mac**

```
Create zip without compression on OS X from Terminal:
zip -r0 zipfilename.zip files-to-zip
```

so we should have to upload this zip in play store.

so you not need to use **ZipHelper.java**

just simply use

```
ZipResourceFile expansionFile=null;

            try {
                expansionFile = APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile(getApplicationContext(),3,0);

                     AssetFileDescriptor fd = expansionFile.getAssetFileDescriptor("test.mp4");
                     MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                     mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                     mPlayer.setDataSource(fd.getFileDescriptor(),fd.getStartOffset(),fd.getLength());
                     mPlayer.prepare();
                     mPlayer.start();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: For those who wan't to do the same under Linux: zip -r -0 main.1.com.my.pkg.obb media_files/

Comment: Hi Sanket,
Can you help me to create obb file?
I need it for one of app.

Comment: @MitulBhalia i've updated my answer for mac. please check it.

Comment: thanks @SanketKachhela but my file structure is little bit different.
Below is the structure

audio -> 1.mp3, 2.mp3
video -> cards -> 1.mp4, 2.mp4
images -> test -> 1.png, 2.png
            -> test1 -> 1.png, 2.png
            -> test2 -> 1.png, 2.png

Comment: sorry for mess up

Let me tell you here

i have all mp3 file in audio folder then all mp4 files in video->cards folders then png files are 3 different folders under images folder

Answer (score 5):

I have solved using unzipping..

ZipHelper.java

```
public class ZipHelper {
static boolean zipError = false;

public static boolean isZipError() {
    return zipError;
}

public static void setZipError(boolean zipError) {
    ZipHelper.zipError = zipError;
}

public static void unzip(String archive, File outputDir) {
    try {
        Log.d("control", "ZipHelper.unzip() - File: " + archive);
        ZipFile zipfile = new ZipFile(archive);
        for (Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> e = zipfile.entries(); e
                .hasMoreElements();) {
            ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) e.nextElement();
            unzipEntry(zipfile, entry, outputDir);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("control", "ZipHelper.unzip() - Error extracting file "
                + archive + ": " + e);
        setZipError(true);
    }
}

private static void unzipEntry(ZipFile zipfile, ZipEntry entry,
        File outputDir) throws IOException {
    if (entry.isDirectory()) {
        createDirectory(new File(outputDir, entry.getName()));
        return;
    }

    File outputFile = new File(outputDir, entry.getName());
    if (!outputFile.getParentFile().exists()) {
        createDirectory(outputFile.getParentFile());
    }

    Log.d("control", "ZipHelper.unzipEntry() - Extracting: " + entry);
    BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(
            zipfile.getInputStream(entry));
    BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream(outputFile));

    try {
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("control", "ZipHelper.unzipEntry() - Error: " + e);
        setZipError(true);
    } finally {
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
    }
}

private static void createDirectory(File dir) {
    Log.d("control",
            "ZipHelper.createDir() - Creating directory: " + dir.getName());
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        if (!dir.mkdirs())
            throw new RuntimeException("Can't create directory " + dir);
    } else
        Log.d("control",
                "ZipHelper.createDir() - Exists directory: "
                        + dir.getName());
}
}
```

Usage

```
try {
        ZipResourceFile expansionFile = APKExpansionSupport
                .getAPKExpansionZipFile(this, 3, 0);

        ZipEntryRO[] zip = expansionFile.getAllEntries();
        Log.e("", "zip[0].isUncompressed() : " + zip[0].isUncompressed());
        Log.e("",
                "mFile.getAbsolutePath() : "
                        + zip[0].mFile.getAbsolutePath());
        Log.e("", "mFileName : " + zip[0].mFileName);
        Log.e("", "mZipFileName : " + zip[0].mZipFileName);
        Log.e("", "mCompressedLength : " + zip[0].mCompressedLength);

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + "");
        ZipHelper.unzip(zip[0].mZipFileName, file);

        if (file.exists()) {
            Log.e("", "unzipped : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: i am getting error at `IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);` in ZipHelper.java please help me..

Comment: Have you tried this http://apache.petsads.us//commons/io/binaries/commons-io-2.4-bin.zip

Comment: one more question...here user be able to delete files of sdcard. so there is any other alternative path to unzip this expansion file.

Answer (score 3):

Are your files inside a folder in the zip file? I ask because I had the same problem and my solution was to include the folder name when getting the file descriptor.

For instance, my expansion file contained a single folder named "Videos". So to get a file descriptor I had to do this:

```
AssetFileDescriptor fd = expansionFile.getAssetFileDescriptor("Videos/" + videoName + ".mp4");
```

Comment: If my .obb file contains 10 different files (.mp3,.jpg,...etc...) How to get each file?. can I get path or File reference for each?

Comment: I think you can just use getAllEntries() like you did in the code you provided. It seems like it would work to me. What does mFile.getAbsolutePath() give you?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `setDataSource()` you are not supposed to compress your files when zipping them in the first place as it says in the docs (http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#ZipLib):

> In order for this to work, you must not perform additional compression
>   on the media files when creating the ZIP packages.