# How to create .obb file as main apk expansion file using jobb tool?

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, apk-expansion-files

I have an apk of 80Mb and so am not able to upload it on google play store. I have googled a lot and found that I have to create `.obb` file as the main expansion file.

Also I have found that I can create a `.obb` file using the [jobb tool](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/jobb.html) which is inside `sdk > tools > jobb.bat` but unfortunately it closes just after it starts.

So am I missing something?

Comment: Please stop creating the `.obb` tag.  .obb files are covered completely under the `apk-expansion-files` tag, which is already on your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have googled and found that we shold have to make .zip with `0% (No compression)` that is mention in http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

`Tip: If you're packaging media files into a ZIP, you can use media playback calls on the files with offset and length controls (such as MediaPlayer.setDataSource() and SoundPool.load()) without the need to unpack your ZIP. In order for this to work, you must not perform additional compression on the media files when creating the ZIP packages. For example, when using the zip tool, you should use the -n option to specify the file suffixes that should not be compressed:
zip -n .mp4;.ogg main_expansion media_files`

OR **How to make 0% compression zip using winrar?**

[image]

here see the compression method

so we should have to upload this zip in play store.

so you not need to use **ZipHelper.java**

just simply use

```
ZipResourceFile expansionFile=null;

            try {
                expansionFile = APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile(getApplicationContext(),3,0);

                     AssetFileDescriptor fd = expansionFile.getAssetFileDescriptor("test.mp4");
                     MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                     mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                     mPlayer.setDataSource(fd.getFileDescriptor(),fd.getStartOffset(),fd.getLength());
                     mPlayer.prepare();
                     mPlayer.start();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: This might serve as a nice example of answering *your own* question incorrectly

Comment: I am using mac to create obb file so can you help me to make obb file?
I have more than one folder in the main assets folder and i do not know how to use zip command to include all the folders.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

$ jobb -d /temp/assets/ -o new-obb-file.obb -k secret-key -pn com.my.app.package -pv 11

Where

```
 -d <directory> : Set the input directory for creating an OBB file. 
 -o <filename>  : Specify the filename for the OBB file.
 -k <key>       : Specify a password for encrypting a new OBB file 
 -pn <package>  : Specify the package name for the application that mounts the OBB file,                which corresponds to the package value specified in your application's manifest. 
 -pv <version>  :   Set the minimum version for the application that can mount the OBB file, which corresponds to the android:versionCode value in your application's manifest.
```

Try this command.

check  following link http://developer.android.com/tools/help/jobb.html

Comment: thanks for answer but where to write this coomand? my jobb tool close itself immediately just after start.

Comment: Don't click on jobb tool , Just go on console and try this command make sure environmental variable is set for tool folder in android sdk

Comment: well i am trying this.

Comment: i have found another and simple way to create a .obb file see there http://stackoverflow.com/a/18953778/942224

Comment: is the key the one used for .keystore ?

Comment: i must create obb with secret key?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create the OBB file with below command BUT the problem was it was not extracted in app and stuck at `ZipInputStream zis zis.getNextEntry()`

`/Users/rohit/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/jobb -d /Users/rohit/Workspace/code/iam/repo/music' 'files -o main.33.com.aml.iatia.activity.obb -pn com.aml.iatia.activity -pv 33`

As a solution, I created using CLI in MAC with below command and it worked very fine.

`zip -r main.33.com.aml.iatia.activity.obb music' 'files -x "*/\.*"`