# Correct way to make an obb file

Tags: java, android, apk-expansion-files

I'm trying to make an obb file and I've been unsuccessful with the JOBB tool see here: [JOBB DirectoryFullException: de.waldheinz.fs.fat.DirectoryFullException: directory is full](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37861753/jobb-directoryfullexception) and when I follow the suggestion found in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21982186/1489990 and I try to access the contents with `ZipFile` as

```
expansionFile =  APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile(context, 46, 1);
InputStream fileStream = expansionFile.getInputStream("/storage/emulated/0/Android/obb/com.nick.app/main.46.com.nick.app.obb/img1large.jpg");
```

This does not work and I get a log message that says `V/zipro: Not a Zip archive.`When I made this OBB file I just selected all of my images and used WinRar to add them to a "ZIP" archive and renamed it to ".OBB". What I'm wondering is to use the `ZipResourceFile` tool are you supposed to create a zip archive of your content, and then add that archive to another archive and rename it to ".OBB"? What is the correct way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Easy Method : get it to ES file explorer(app in android) you will see it as .zip then rename it as .obb and also this renaming method is not possible in windows