# APK Expansion Files. Testing sample

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I read this [Steps to create APK expansion file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715855/steps-to-create-apk-expansion-file), 
run `SampleDownloaderActivity` and get: "Download failed because the resources could not be found"

How to create a `Test Project` (simple project >50MB with big pics) and then upload it on Google Play and testing APK Expansion Files?

Comment: I am also getting same issue.If you found any solution.Can you please reply or give me  a link.Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This is rather late, but I'm currently doing it this way...

I'm following these instructions found here:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2481797?hl=en

There is a lot more information here: http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

You will have to upload the APK and publish the application to test the expansion files.
Use the ALPHA option so that the application is not visible to everyone.

After the application is published you can test your expansion file correctly.  If you are planning a paid application, instead of paying just upload your APK from Eclipse or Android Studio directly.

As for your error.  You will have to make sure you "publish" and that the application is visible in the play store before you will have access to the expansion files for testing.

I have also read in many other posts that you may test expansion files while in draft mode. 
This is now FALSE.  explained here https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6062777?hl=en

Comment: I wanted to be sure the download works for a paid app, without paing... but this is impossible,,, free app change is forever.
The only way is to create a dummy app for free, test it in aplha and then delete it... quite a long work for a test...