# IOUtils Exception Android

Tags: android

I am implementing Expansion Files . I use technique to read zip files from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715855/steps-to-create-apk-expansion-file). Every thing fine the only error i am getting is on IOUtils. Which says IOUtils cannot be resolved. My project api level is 3.0 and above.

Here is the lline :

```
 **IOUtils**.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
```

Comment: what library does IOUtils come from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IOUtils class is available as Apache Commons library. Probably you need to download the jar and put it inside the libs directory before you can use it.

Or add the following line to your build.gradle and sync your project.

```
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'
```

Comment: Quick googling gives the link. http://apache.techartifact.com/mirror//commons/io/binaries/commons-io-2.4-bin.zip

Comment: @Gopinath, that link gives a 404.  Perhaps a link to maven central or a maven <dependency> definition would be more appropriate?