# What to import to use IOUtils.toString()?

Tags: java, apache, io, tostring

I am trying to use IOUtils.toString() to read from a file.
However, I am getting an error saying "IOUtils cannot be resolved."

What am I supposed to be importing to allow me to use this function?

```
String everything = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
```

Thanks

Comment: Use this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768166/ioutils-exception-android

Answer (score 56):

**import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;**

If you still can't import add to pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

or for direct jar/gradle etc visit:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.5

Also since version 2.5 of commons-io method IOUtils.toString(inputStream) has been deprecated. You should use method with Encoding i.e.

```java
IOUtils.toString(is, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Is it deprecated in favor of what method?

Comment: Same method name but with one additional parameter - encoding.
'IOUtils.toString(is, "UTF-8");'

Comment: This is eating all my memory

Comment: Of course!  Why would it not be something like  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId> or similar?  Gaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  thanks for answer.

Comment: For more relevant deprecation info please see the official document at https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/deprecated-list.html.

Answer (score 15):

`import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;`

Comment: Unable to import this. Please help

Comment: Check the answer of @Fryta, you need to add a library to your project.

Answer (score 11):

[Fryta's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37667720/151004) outline how to actually use IOUtils and [snj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52915943/151004) is good for files.

If you're on java 9 or later and you have an input stream to read you can use [InputStream#readAllBytes()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#readAllBytes--). Just create a string from there and don't forget to specify charset.

```
String s = new String(inputStream.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me.. running Java v17.

Comment: When the `inputStream` originates from a `Path` (or a `File` which you can [easily convert to a `Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#toPath())), you can use [`String s = Files.readString(path);`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readString(java.nio.file.Path)) in the first place. Otherwise, this `readAllBytes()` based solution is the most pragmatic approach.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can try following way. It worked for me for reading public key for resource server

```
        final Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("public.key");
        String publicKey = null;
        try {
            publicKey = new String(Files.readAllBytes(resource.getFile().toPath()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Why did you add jar there ?

Comment: I am using nohup to run java project.

Comment: It should work for jar also even if you are running jar in background in linux machine. Please share the error.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code for How to convert InputStream to String in Java using Apache IOUtils

Reference : https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(FILE_LOCATION);
String StringFromInputStream = IOUtils.toString(fis, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(StringFromInputStream);
```

Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

The following import statement would be required:

**import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;**

If the error "**The import org.apache.commons.io cannot be resolved**" shows up, add the **commons-io-2.6.jar** to the **project Java buildpath** and/or to the project **lib folder**.

Note: The suggestion to import "import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;" usually doesn't appear in Eclipse IDE at least in the context of this question.