# Android Expansion Files - resource not found when testing

Tags: android, expansion

This is my package name: com.abc.ss

Now i have manually created a folder with package name com.abc.s in mnt/sdcard/Android/obb/com.abc.ss/main.2.com.abc.ss.obb

But when i run the sample app it says Downloading failed:

Here is my screen shot:

[image]

Here my code;

```
public class SampleDownloaderActivity extends Activity implements IDownloaderClient {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "LVLDownloader";
    private ProgressBar mPB;

    private TextView mStatusText;
    private TextView mProgressFraction;
    private TextView mProgressPercent;
    private TextView mAverageSpeed;
    private TextView mTimeRemaining;

    private View mDashboard;
    private View mCellMessage;

    private Button mPauseButton;
    private Button mWiFiSettingsButton;

    private boolean mStatePaused;
    private int mState;

    private IDownloaderService mRemoteService;

    private IStub mDownloaderClientStub;

    private void setState(int newState) {
        if (mState != newState) {
            mState = newState;
            mStatusText.setText(Helpers.getDownloaderStringResourceIDFromState(newState));
        }
    }

    private void setButtonPausedState(boolean paused) {
        mStatePaused = paused;
        int stringResourceID = paused ? R.string.text_button_resume :
                R.string.text_button_pause;
        mPauseButton.setText(stringResourceID);
    }

    /**
     * This is a little helper class that demonstrates simple testing of an
     * Expansion APK file delivered by Market. You may not wish to hard-code
     * things such as file lengths into your executable... and you may wish to
     * turn this code off during application development.
     */
    private static class XAPKFile {
        public final boolean mIsMain;
        public final int mFileVersion;
        public final long mFileSize;

        XAPKFile(boolean isMain, int fileVersion, long fileSize) {
            mIsMain = isMain;
            mFileVersion = fileVersion;
            mFileSize = fileSize;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Here is where you place the data that the validator will use to determine
     * if the file was delivered correctly. This is encoded in the source code
     * so the application can easily determine whether the file has been
     * properly delivered without having to talk to the server. If the
     * application is using LVL for licensing, it may make sense to eliminate
     * these checks and to just rely on the server.
     */
    private static final XAPKFile[] xAPKS = {
            new XAPKFile(
                    true, // true signifies a main file
                    2, // the version of the APK that the file was uploaded
                       // against
                    23232840L // the length of the file in bytes
            ),
            new XAPKFile(
                    false, // false signifies a patch file
                    4, // the version of the APK that the patch file was uploaded
                       // against
                    512860L // the length of the patch file in bytes
            )            
    };

    /**
     * Go through each of the APK Expansion files defined in the structure above
     * and determine if the files are present and match the required size. Free
     * applications should definitely consider doing this, as this allows the
     * application to be launched for the first time without having a network
     * connection present. Paid applications that use LVL should probably do at
     * least one LVL check that requires the network to be present, so this is
     * not as necessary.
     * 
     * @return true if they are present.
     */
    boolean expansionFilesDelivered() {
        for (XAPKFile xf : xAPKS) {
            String fileName = Helpers.getExpansionAPKFileName(this, xf.mIsMain, xf.mFileVersion);
            if (!Helpers.doesFileExist(this, fileName, xf.mFileSize, false)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Calculating a moving average for the validation speed so we don't get
     * jumpy calculations for time etc.
     */
    static private final float SMOOTHING_FACTOR = 0.005f;

    /**
     * Used by the async task
     */
    private boolean mCancelValidation;

    /**
     * Go through each of the Expansion APK files and open each as a zip file.
     * Calculate the CRC for each file and return false if any fail to match.
     * 
     * @return true if XAPKZipFile is successful
     */
    void validateXAPKZipFiles() {
        AsyncTask<Object, DownloadProgressInfo, Boolean> validationTask = new AsyncTask<Object, DownloadProgressInfo, Boolean>() {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                mDashboard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mCellMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mStatusText.setText(R.string.text_verifying_download);
                mPauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        mCancelValidation = true;
                    }
                });
                mPauseButton.setText(R.string.text_button_cancel_verify);
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Object... params) {
                for (XAPKFile xf : xAPKS) {
                    String fileName = Helpers.getExpansionAPKFileName(
                            SampleDownloaderActivity.this,
                            xf.mIsMain, xf.mFileVersion);
                    if (!Helpers.doesFileExist(SampleDownloaderActivity.this, fileName,
                            xf.mFileSize, false)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    fileName = Helpers
                            .generateSaveFileName(SampleDownloaderActivity.this, fileName);
                    ZipResourceFile zrf;
                    byte[] buf = new byte[1024 * 256];
                    try {
                        zrf = new ZipResourceFile(fileName);
                        ZipEntryRO[] entries = zrf.getAllEntries();
                        /**
                         * First calculate the total compressed length
                         */
                        long totalCompressedLength = 0;
                        for (ZipEntryRO entry : entries) {
                            totalCompressedLength += entry.mCompressedLength;
                        }
                        float averageVerifySpeed = 0;
                        long totalBytesRemaining = totalCompressedLength;
                        long timeRemaining;
                        /**
                         * Then calculate a CRC for every file in the Zip file,
                         * comparing it to what is stored in the Zip directory.
                         * Note that for compressed Zip files we must extract
                         * the contents to do this comparison.
                         */
                        for (ZipEntryRO entry : entries) {
                            if (-1 != entry.mCRC32) {
                                long length = entry.mUncompressedLength;
                                CRC32 crc = new CRC32();
                                DataInputStream dis = null;
                                try {
                                    dis = new DataInputStream(
                                            zrf.getInputStream(entry.mFileName));

                                    long startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                                    while (length > 0) {
                                        int seek = (int) (length > buf.length ? buf.length
                                                : length);
                                        dis.readFully(buf, 0, seek);
                                        crc.update(buf, 0, seek);
                                        length -= seek;
                                        long currentTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                                        long timePassed = currentTime - startTime;
                                        if (timePassed > 0) {
                                            float currentSpeedSample = (float) seek
                                                    / (float) timePassed;
                                            if (0 != averageVerifySpeed) {
                                                averageVerifySpeed = SMOOTHING_FACTOR
                                                        * currentSpeedSample
                                                        + (1 - SMOOTHING_FACTOR)
                                                        * averageVerifySpeed;
                                            } else {
                                                averageVerifySpeed = currentSpeedSample;
                                            }
                                            totalBytesRemaining -= seek;
                                            timeRemaining = (long) (totalBytesRemaining / averageVerifySpeed);
                                            this.publishProgress(
                                                    new DownloadProgressInfo(
                                                            totalCompressedLength,
                                                            totalCompressedLength
                                                                    - totalBytesRemaining,
                                                            timeRemaining,
                                                            averageVerifySpeed)
                                                    );
                                        }
                                        startTime = currentTime;
                                        if (mCancelValidation) {
                                            return true;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if (crc.getValue() != entry.mCRC32) {
                                        Log.e(Constants.TAG,
                                                "CRC does not match for entry: "
                                                        + entry.mFileName);
                                        Log.e(Constants.TAG,
                                                "In file: " + entry.getZipFileName());
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                } finally {
                                    if (null != dis) {
                                        dis.close();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(DownloadProgressInfo... values) {
                onDownloadProgress(values[0]);
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                if (result) {
                    mDashboard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mCellMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mStatusText.setText(R.string.text_validation_complete);
                    mPauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
                    mPauseButton.setText(android.R.string.ok);
                } else {
                    mDashboard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mCellMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mStatusText.setText(R.string.text_validation_failed);
                    mPauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
                    mPauseButton.setText(android.R.string.cancel);
                }
                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }

        };
        validationTask.execute(new Object());
    }

    /**
     * If the download isn't present, we initialize the download UI. This ties
     * all of the controls into the remote service calls.
     */
    private void initializeDownloadUI() {
        mDownloaderClientStub = DownloaderClientMarshaller.CreateStub
                (this, SampleDownloaderService.class);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mPB = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mStatusText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusText);
        mProgressFraction = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.progressAsFraction);
        mProgressPercent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.progressAsPercentage);
        mAverageSpeed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.progressAverageSpeed);
        mTimeRemaining = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.progressTimeRemaining);
        mDashboard = findViewById(R.id.downloaderDashboard);
        mCellMessage = findViewById(R.id.approveCellular);
        mPauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);
        mWiFiSettingsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wifiSettingsButton);

        mPauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mStatePaused) {
                    mRemoteService.requestContinueDownload();
                } else {
                    mRemoteService.requestPauseDownload();
                }
                setButtonPausedState(!mStatePaused);
            }
        });

        mWiFiSettingsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
            }
        });

        Button resumeOnCell = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resumeOverCellular);
        resumeOnCell.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mRemoteService.setDownloadFlags(IDownloaderService.FLAGS_DOWNLOAD_OVER_CELLULAR);
                mRemoteService.requestContinueDownload();
                mCellMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first create; we wouldn't create a layout in
     * the case where we have the file and are moving to another activity
     * without downloading.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /**
         * Both downloading and validation make use of the "download" UI
         */
        initializeDownloadUI();

        /**
         * Before we do anything, are the files we expect already here and
         * delivered (presumably by Market) For free titles, this is probably
         * worth doing. (so no Market request is necessary)
         */
        if (!expansionFilesDelivered()) {

            try {
                Intent launchIntent = SampleDownloaderActivity.this
                        .getIntent();
                Intent intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification = new Intent(
                        SampleDownloaderActivity
                        .this, SampleDownloaderActivity.this.getClass());
                intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification.setAction(launchIntent.getAction());

                if (launchIntent.getCategories() != null) {
                    for (String category : launchIntent.getCategories()) {
                        intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification.addCategory(category);
                    }
                }

                // Build PendingIntent used to open this activity from
                // Notification
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        SampleDownloaderActivity.this,
                        0, intentToLaunchThisActivityFromNotification,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                // Request to start the download
                int startResult = DownloaderClientMarshaller.startDownloadServiceIfRequired(this,
                        pendingIntent, SampleDownloaderService.class);

                if (startResult != DownloaderClientMarshaller.NO_DOWNLOAD_REQUIRED) {
                    // The DownloaderService has started downloading the files,
                    // show progress
                    initializeDownloadUI();
                    return;
                } // otherwise, download not needed so we fall through to
                  // starting the movie
            } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot find own package! MAYDAY!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            validateXAPKZipFiles();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Connect the stub to our service on start.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        if (null != mDownloaderClientStub) {
            mDownloaderClientStub.connect(this);
        }
        super.onStart();
    }

    /**
     * Disconnect the stub from our service on stop
     */
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if (null != mDownloaderClientStub) {
            mDownloaderClientStub.disconnect(this);
        }
        super.onStop();
    }

    /**
     * Critical implementation detail. In onServiceConnected we create the
     * remote service and marshaler. This is how we pass the client information
     * back to the service so the client can be properly notified of changes. We
     * must do this every time we reconnect to the service.
     */
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(Messenger m) {
        mRemoteService = DownloaderServiceMarshaller.CreateProxy(m);
        mRemoteService.onClientUpdated(mDownloaderClientStub.getMessenger());
    }

    /**
     * The download state should trigger changes in the UI --- it may be useful
     * to show the state as being indeterminate at times. This sample can be
     * considered a guideline.
     */
    @Override
    public void onDownloadStateChanged(int newState) {
        setState(newState);
        boolean showDashboard = true;
        boolean showCellMessage = false;
        boolean paused;
        boolean indeterminate;
        switch (newState) {
            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_IDLE:
                // STATE_IDLE means the service is listening, so it's
                // safe to start making calls via mRemoteService.
                paused = false;
                indeterminate = true;
                break;
            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_CONNECTING:
            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_FETCHING_URL:
                showDashboard = true;
                paused = false;
                indeterminate = true;
                break;
            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_DOWNLOADING:
                paused = false;
                showDashboard = true;
                indeterminate = false;
                break;

            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_FAILED_CANCELED:
            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_FAILED:
            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_FAILED_FETCHING_URL:
            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_FAILED_UNLICENSED:
                paused = true;
                showDashboard = false;
                indeterminate = false;
                break;
            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_PAUSED_NEED_CELLULAR_PERMISSION:
            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_PAUSED_WIFI_DISABLED_NEED_CELLULAR_PERMISSION:
                showDashboard = false;
                paused = true;
                indeterminate = false;
                showCellMessage = true;
                break;

            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_PAUSED_BY_REQUEST:
                paused = true;
                indeterminate = false;
                break;
            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_PAUSED_ROAMING:
            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_PAUSED_SDCARD_UNAVAILABLE:
                paused = true;
                indeterminate = false;
                break;
            case IDownloaderClient.STATE_COMPLETED:
                showDashboard = false;
                paused = false;
                indeterminate = false;
                validateXAPKZipFiles();
                return;
            default:
                paused = true;
                indeterminate = true;
                showDashboard = true;
        }
        int newDashboardVisibility = showDashboard ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE;
        if (mDashboard.getVisibility() != newDashboardVisibility) {
            mDashboard.setVisibility(newDashboardVisibility);
        }
        int cellMessageVisibility = showCellMessage ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE;
        if (mCellMessage.getVisibility() != cellMessageVisibility) {
            mCellMessage.setVisibility(cellMessageVisibility);
        }

        mPB.setIndeterminate(indeterminate);
        setButtonPausedState(paused);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the state of the various controls based on the progressinfo object
     * sent from the downloader service.
     */
    @Override
    public void onDownloadProgress(DownloadProgressInfo progress) {
        mAverageSpeed.setText(getString(R.string.kilobytes_per_second,
                Helpers.getSpeedString(progress.mCurrentSpeed)));
        mTimeRemaining.setText(getString(R.string.time_remaining,
                Helpers.getTimeRemaining(progress.mTimeRemaining)));

        //mAverageSpeed.setText("" + Helpers.getSpeedString(progress.mCurrentSpeed));
      //  mTimeRemaining.setText("" + Helpers.getTimeRemaining(progress.mTimeRemaining));

        progress.mOverallTotal = progress.mOverallTotal;
        mPB.setMax((int) (progress.mOverallTotal >> 8));
        mPB.setProgress((int) (progress.mOverallProgress >> 8));
        mProgressPercent.setText(Long.toString(progress.mOverallProgress
                * 100 /
                progress.mOverallTotal) + "%");
        mProgressFraction.setText(Helpers.getDownloadProgressString
                (progress.mOverallProgress,
                        progress.mOverallTotal));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        this.mCancelValidation = true;
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

what is wrong with this?

EDIT:

XAPKFile[] xAPK is the place where we have given like its a main,filesize and version code

expansionFilesDelivered()  is the method where it checks for the filename

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @MattTaylor i am trying to test the obb file present in the sdcard that i have manually added

Comment: Can you tell me where am i going wrong? i am stuck fromlong time

Comment: Are you sure that's the app should be looking for it? That that's the location the Play store downloads it to?

Comment: yes see here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715855/steps-to-create-apk-expansion-file/11717019#11717019

Comment: TBH I'm not overly keen on sifting through all of the code you've posted to find the relevant bit. Cut it down so that it's clear **where** your invalid check is occurring, then I might take a look

Comment: @Goofy it's because no resource found at google server (google play dev console) for your app

Comment: @Subra no as i said i havent uploaded the app in the market, i am just testing the app by manually adding the obb file in the Android/obb/... folder. at that time even though i have added the obb file in the specified folder it says that msg can we test it like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like Condition failed to find your file in sdcard

```
 boolean expansionFilesDelivered() {
    for (XAPKFile xf : xAPKS) {
        String fileName = Helpers.getExpansionAPKFileName(this, xf.mIsBase, xf.mFileVersion);
        if (!Helpers.doesFileExist(this, fileName, xf.mFileSize, false))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

have put the fake file in exact directory?

```
private final static String EXP_PATH = "/Android/obb/";

static String[] getAPKExpansionFiles(Context ctx, int mainVersion, int patchVersion) {
    String packageName = ctx.getPackageName();
    Vector<String> ret = new Vector<String>();
    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        // Build the full path to the app's expansion files
        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File expPath = new File(root.toString() + EXP_PATH + packageName);

        // Check that expansion file path exists
        if (expPath.exists()) {
            if ( mainVersion > 0 ) {
                String strMainPath = expPath + File.separator + "main." +
                        mainVersion + "." + packageName + ".obb";
                File main = new File(strMainPath);
                if ( main.isFile() ) {
                        ret.add(strMainPath);
                }
            }
            if ( patchVersion > 0 ) {
                String strPatchPath = expPath + File.separator + "patch." +
                        mainVersion + "." + packageName + ".obb";
                File main = new File(strPatchPath);
                if ( main.isFile() ) {
                        ret.add(strPatchPath);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    String[] retArray = new String[ret.size()];
    ret.toArray(retArray);
    return retArray;
}
```

you should push the (obb fake file) file in here  (com.your.packagename)
[image]  with your package name (package name should ve created programatically)

```
    String xapkFilePath = getAPKExpansionFiles(SampleDownloaderActivity.this);
                Log.d("CopyFromAPKEXP", "OBBFileName: " + xapkFilePath);
                String exportDirectory = Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                        + "/Android/data/"
                        + SampleDownloaderActivity.this.getPackageName()
                        + "/files/";
                File exportDirectoryFilepath = new File(exportDirectory);

                exportDirectoryFilepath.mkdirs();
```

Comment: i think thats why it was always returning ture , if i dont add the obb file ,ok i need to replace this with my existing method? if so where do i ned to add this ? i mean in which class?

Comment: where is this method buddy? i am not able to find it?

Comment: i got this will gibe me an array get an array containing the complete path to expansion files, but when do i need to call this?

Comment: thanks a lot, but still i am not getting i have few more issues? can i ask you? i am stuck from 1 day

Comment: @Goofy your project package name visible in ddms?? file explore? you can give a try by hard coding boolean expansionFilesDelivered()  to true :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25141/discussion-between-goofy-and-subra)

Comment: can you please join there?

Comment: @can you please join here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25141/discussion-between-goofy-and-subra

Answer (score 0):

I had the message running from the simulator, from an actual device everything went OK...could have to do with License stuff, check your logging, if you see something with License errors, that's it