# APK expansion file expPath does not exists

Tags: android, apk

I have been trying to convert my App to use an APK Expansion file and for some reason this code below cannot find the path to my APK Expansion file ...

```
static String[] getAPKExpansionFiles(Context ctx, int mainVersion, int patchVersion) {
    Log.v(TAG, "Utils.getAPKExpansionFiles [27] mainVersion is " + mainVersion + " patchVersion = " + patchVersion );
    String packageName = ctx.getPackageName();
    Log.v(TAG, "Utils.getAPKExpansionFiles [27] packageName is [" + packageName + "]" );
    Vector<String> ret = new Vector<String>();
    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Utils.getAPKExpansionFiles [32] MEDIA_MOUNTED" );
        // Build the full path to the app's expansion files
        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        Log.v(TAG, "Utils.getAPKExpansionFiles [35] root = " + root);
        File expPath = new File(root.toString() + EXP_PATH + packageName);
        Log.v(TAG, "Utils.getAPKExpansionFiles [37] expPath " + expPath );

        // Check that expansion file path exists
        if (expPath.exists()) {
                ...
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, "Utils.getAPKExpansionFiles [60] expPath DOES NOT EXISTS" );
        }
    } else {
        Log.v(TAG, "Utils.getAPKExpansionFiles [57] NOT MEDIA_MOUNTED" );
    }
    String[] retArray = new String[ret.size()];
    ret.toArray(retArray);
    return retArray;
}
```

... logcat shows this ...

```
03-20 21:04:24.206: V/GospelofMatthewAudiobook(10965): Utils.getAPKExpansionFiles [37] expPath /mnt/sdcard/Android/obb/com.redcricket.GospelofMatthewAudiobook
03-20 21:04:24.214: V/GospelofMatthewAudiobook(10965): Utils.getAPKExpansionFiles [60] expPath DOES NOT EXISTS
```

... even though the path does exists and the file is there as demonstrated in this screen shot:

[image] 
I am pretty certain I do not have a typo and the path exists.  So why would `expPath.exists()` return false.

Thanks for the answer Ted ... but I still get this in the logcat ....

```
03-20 21:59:48.198: V/GospelofMatthewAudiobook(11988): Utils.getAPKExpansionFiles [37] expPath /mnt/sdcard/Android/obb/com.redcricket.GospelofMatthewAudiobook/main.1.com.redcricket.GospelofMatthewAudiobook.obb
03-20 21:59:48.198: V/GospelofMatthewAudiobook(11988): Utils.getAPKExpansionFiles [60] expPath DOES NOT EXISTS
```

... could it be that I created the directories with Windows and not `avd`.  What would the `adb` command be to create the dirs and push the APK expansion zip file on to my phone?

Comment: I found `adb.exe` in `C:\Users\dogface\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>`

Comment: I tried this commmand: `C:\Users\dogface\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb.exe push c
:\main.1.com.redcricket.GospelofMatthewAudiobook.obb /mnt/sdcard/Android/obb/com
.redcricket.GospelofMatthewAudiobook\main.1.com.redcricket.GospelofMatthewAudiob
ook.obb
failed to copy 'c:\main.1.com.redcricket.GospelofMatthewAudiobook.obb' to '/mnt/
sdcard/Android/obb/com.redcricket.GospelofMatthewAudiobook\main.1.com.redcricket
.GospelofMatthewAudiobook.obb': Permission denied

C:\Users\dogface\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to name the file itself. Instead of this:

```
File expPath = new File(root.toString() + EXP_PATH + packageName);
```

use this:

```
File expPathDir = new File(root.toString() + EXP_PATH + packageName);
File expPath = new File(expPathDir,
    String.format("main.%d.%s.obb", mainVersion, packageName));
```

This will work for a main expansion pack. You should have a similar method for accessing a patch that uses the format `String.format("patch.%d.%s.obb", patchVersion, packageName)`

The full path to the file should be something like

```
/mnt/sdcard/Android/obb/com.redcricket.GospelofMatthewAudiobook/main.123./mnt/sdcard/Android/obb/com.redcricket.GospelofMatthewAudiobook.obb
```

Comment: shouldn't the **%i** be __%d__ ?

Comment: could your answer also be applied to my answer? But it didn't work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33553722/obb-opaque-binary-blobb-getmountedobbpath-returning-null

Comment: @java - Yes, `%i` should have been `%d`. Thanks for the catch. I'll look at your other question.

Comment: would be very glad if you took time :-)