# Obb (Opaque Binary Blobb) getMountedObbPath() returning null

Tags: android, large-files, apk-expansion-files

Why is the obb-file not found when its actually there?

in the `logcat` window

```
 11-05 20:42:33.860: I/System.out(7563): mainFile = /storage/sdcard0/Android/obb/main.11.se.sourses.thai.obb

11-05 20:42:33.860: I/System.out(7563): main = null
```

the codesnippet

```
    StorageManager storage = (StorageManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(STORAGE_SERVICE);
    File mainFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/obb/" +
               "main." + 11 + "." + "se.sourses.thai" + ".obb");
    String main = storage.getMountedObbPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/obb/");
    System.out.println("mainFile = " + mainFile);
    System.out.println("main = " + main);
```

according to the documentation getMountedObbPath returns the following:

*Check the mounted path of an Opaque Binary Blob (OBB) file. This will give you the path to where you can obtain access to the internals of the OBB.Parameters:rawPath path to OBB imageReturns:absolute path to mounted OBB image data or null if not mounted or exception encountered trying to read status*

Yes - in my case you can see that main returns *null*

So what could be wrong

- the `.obb` file is there (see image)
- the `packagename` is correct (min. `sdk` is set to 11)

So - why is the `getMountedObbPath()` returning null when the file is actually there? How can I make this work?

[image]

[image]

tried with this answer but it did not work.

[APK expansion file expPath does not exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15539455/apk-expansion-file-exppath-does-not-exists)

Mycode:

```
    String packageName = this.getPackageName();
    String EXP_PATH = "/Android/obb/";
    File expPathDir = new File(root.toString() + EXP_PATH + packageName);   
    int mainVersion = 11;
    File expPath = new File(expPathDir,
    String.format("main.%d.%s.obb", mainVersion, packageName));
    StorageManager storage = (StorageManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(STORAGE_SERVICE);
    boolean b = storage.isObbMounted(expPath.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println("ismounted = " + b);
```

it returns false.

expPath outputs the string:

```
  expPath = /storage/sdcard0/Android/obb/se.sources.thai/main.11.se.sources.thai.obb
```

Edit:

I've even created another subfolder to the obb-file (according to Developer.Android). So now the path to the obb-file is:

```
/storage/sdcard0/Android/obb/se.sources.thai/main.11.se.sources.thai.obb
```

But its not working

Comment: is it worked for you? I am also stuck with same?