# NOT_LICENSED cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, apk

I have been trying to follow the documentation available here:

http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#Preparing

I have tried to follow what it says to do ...

If you're using Eclipse, create a project for each library and add it to your app:

Create a new Library Project for the License Verification Library and Downloader Library. For each library:

- Begin a new Android project.
- Select Create project from existing source and choose the library from the /extras/google/ directory (market_licensing/ for the License Verification Library or market_apk_expansion/downloader_library/ for the Downloader Library).

Of course there was no `market_licensing` or `market_apk_expansion/downloader_library/` directories so I guess that I am suppose to use the `play_licensing` and `market_apk_expansion/downloader_library` directories. :/

- Specify a Project Name such as "Google Play License Library" and "Google Play Downloader Library"
  Click Finish.
- Add the License Verification Library to the Downloader Library's project properties (same process as steps 2 and 3 below).
- Right-click the Android project in which you want to use APK expansion files and select Properties.
  In the Library panel, click Add to select and add each of the libraries to your application.

So yes I have read the docs and did my best to follow them, but now I get this error ...[image]

I am starting to think there is a bug in the latest Android SDK here is what the properties of the Downloader Lib look like right after installing and add to ecliplse ...
[image]

... so I updated it like so ...

[image]

Comment: How do I do that?  And what do you mean "your Activity" I haven't added the download / licensing stuff to my app yet, because the library it needs does not compile.

Comment: Sorry, I read it wrong. Was doing too many things at once

Comment: No problem ... any replies are welcomed :)

Comment: I have given up trying to make this work via eclipse.  I do not have these problems with `ant` on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To correct the problem I had to remove the downloader library I had imported and then
use the Android SDK manager to uninstall the "Google Play APK Expansion Library" then re-install it.  Then in eclispe re-import downloader lib and then 'right click' the downloader project and remove the bad library 'market_licensing' and add the correct library 'play_licensing'

Comment: Update. Actually I have given up trying to use eclipse.  Instead I am using `bash/vim/ant` as my IDE choice on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

In this case, the imported class `Policy` is basic google class.

so remove import line `import java.security.Policy`

and than add import line `import com.google.android.vending.licensing.Policy`