# Android: add some file with my .apk

Tags: android

I have one question, how can I install to the users phone some sound file which is needed to my application?
I just want that, after download from market, user have all files which is needed for working with my app...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way:

Save those in `\res\raw` folder then:

```
InputStream databaseInputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.yourfile);
```

And that's how you can btain them, beware thought, that of all those files + the apk exceed 50 MB, you'll have to prepare an expansion file (see [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html)).

Answer (score 5):

You can reduce the size of your sound files and keep it in raw or asset folder,
To reduce the size of sound file you can use this [`software`](http://mp3resizer.en.softonic.com/) on windows

Be sure that your apk size must be less than 50MB, or follow the [`link`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11717019/1208563) to achieve the alternate solution

May this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Install all these files from server when application first start. You can use [Shareprefrences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to save the value so that download will work only once.

**Or**

if you do not have more files then you can keep them inside **Assets**