# how to upload apk file if size more than 50 MB

Tags: android, apk

I am new to Android app development. My application has a size of 90MB and exceeds the Google Play limit. The developer console suggests to use APK expansion and to create an obb file. But I do not understand how to create an obb file and APK expansion. Does anyone know a better way to do that without changing any code in my application?

Thanks in advance. I'd like to see samples or tutorials about this topic.

Comment: see this http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Comment: you can go through this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715855/steps-to-create-apk-expansion-file

Comment: i saw the developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html . but i am not getting how to make perfectly. its give me NUll pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a late answer, but it may help others who encounter a similar issue:

**As of recently** (Sept. 2015)**, you are able to upload APKs up to 100 MB** if you are targeting Android 2.3 and above - you can read more about it [on this help page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2481797?hl=en-GB). Since your app is 90 MB, you should be okay. There is also the Android developers blogspot article explaining the changes [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/09/support-for-100mb-apks-on-google-play.html).

Alternatively, or if your app exceeds the 100 MB APK limit, you can use **expansion files**. These are additional files that are downloaded after your app has installed and can be up to 4 GB (to be specific, you can have two expansion files of up to 2 GB each). You can learn more about expansion files on [this page on the Android Developers website](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html).

However, note that there are some limitations to using expansion files, apart from the 2 GB limit per file such as the fact that the user must have downloaded your app through Google Play. More details on these can also be found on the Android Developers page linked above.