# Store application data in sd card manually in encrypted form

Tags: android, file-io, android-sdcard

I have 2-300 MBs of application data that is images/videos and audio files, i want to save all these data in encrypted form, and can not be seen/deleted by user while exploring sd card. Can anyone help me for doing this.

Comment: change the file extension as unreadable.

Comment: @Andru Changing file extension will only protect it from users that doesn't know how to rename files on the SD-card, or those who doesn't know that no matter the file extension, the contents will still be the same and it's still readable by many apps

Answer (score 2):

> and can not be seen/deleted by user while exploring sd card

This is not possible. Users have the right to get to whatever they want on external storage, including deleting it.

Rooted device users can further get to everything on the device, including internal storage. Since there are relatively few rooted device users, you could put your files on internal storage on Android 3.0+.

Answer (score 1):

You can use APK expansion file.
so it will not seen by user. user can delete that file so you have to check on application start up that this file is available or not?

More info regarding [apk expansion](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html)  and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11717019/942224)

Comment: That is fine but i dont want to publish application on google play store, i want to sell this application separately on user`s device

Comment: @Badoniya than what is problem to put asset or drawable folder of app? app folder is not accessible from user side.