# Adding android expansion file to my project

Tags: android, file, expansion

So I guess I'm still pretty new to Java / Android, and have been struggling for a few days trying to add the android expansion files to my project. It has gotten to the point where I would rather just pay someone to add it to my project, and then I can work backwards from there learning how it works. Would anyone be up to the challenge?

Regards,
Jimmy

Edit: Ok, so I'm willing to put $100 up for anyone that can implement the code for loading expansion files into my project. This thing has pissed me off for over a week now and I still can't get it fully implemented (got a fair bit further than last week, still can't get it to 100%). Anyone up for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "expansion"?

Comment: The files you add to a project so you can use the android expansion files.
http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html for reference

Comment: So have you read [the official developer site](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html) about it, or checking for [tutorials with code](http://ankitthakkar90.blogspot.com/2013/01/apk-expansion-files-in-android-with.html)?

Comment: Yeah, so far the two tutorials I have mainly been trying are:
http://ankitthakkar90.blogspot.com.au/2013/01/apk-expansion-files-in-android-with.html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715855/steps-to-create-apk-expansion-file

I guess I just don't understand enough about java or something to be able to pull it off. Can't find any videos about it on youtube either, which sucks...

Comment: Haha this is why I came to the point of just offering someone cash to add the code in...

Comment: I haven't used those, but if you state exactly what you tried and what issues you have with that, people that have used it would be more willing to help.

Comment: Ah this all stems from me teaching myself Java, so far I can have SDK download the two sets of files I need, and I can import them into the project (ie clicking the buttons), but then red lines appear Everywhere and I have no clue where to go next. I have tried just dragging the packages into my game... can't seem to get that to work either.

Screen shot of where I am up to: http://imgur.com/Zn0kztN

Comment: Also, many thanks for taking the time to chat :D

Comment: This has nothing to do with expansion. You need to export files to your project, correct? What types are they?
Edit: By "this" I meant the red lines, and what you are doing (dragging files, etc)
Edit2: Also, I will be going for now, will check later.

Comment: Yeah I need to take some files from the android SDK downloader and import them into my project, so I can load the expansion file I created.

Comment: What the top red line means is that you don't have the package in your project. If you need to import a library, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642928/adding-a-library-jar-to-an-eclipse-android-project) will help you. If you have just copied the code directly, change the package names since they don't correspond to your package (which is `com.skyrar.newgame.downloader`).

Comment: Thanks for your help Yordan, would you mind if I messaged you in the future if I have other questions?

Comment: Sure, if I have time/knowledge, I will try to aid.