# Android APK Expansion Zip File Total Files Limit?

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I am trying to play mp3 files from my app's apk expansion files. It was zip with no compression and it works well when the total files are about 20k. But after i added more files to around 50k files then getAssetFileDescriptor will simply return null. I tried reduced total files to about 20k again and it works so i am guessing there is a limit on total files in an apk expansion zip file?
Is there a way to overcome the limit?

Btw the expansion file size with 50k files is only 1gb which is still within the limit of 2gb.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11717019/1576416 see this

Comment: Hmm unzipping 50k files in the phone!?