# Can anyone help me out Step-by-Step for APK expansion

Tags: android, apk, apk-expansion-files

I have developed a android project for kid learning which is using 100 of `.mp3` files and `.gif` file.

Now i am unable to upload it on google play store as it accepts only max of 50 MB Apk file. So there is need to Apk expansion.
My question is here,

1. How will i implement it practically , i have read many post regarding it but can't find proper solution.
2. How will i access the `.mp3` & `.gif` files in application.
3. If i delete the `.mp3` & `.gif` files then my projects contains errors, How can i manage it.

Your are most welcome & apreciate for sharing your views & suggestions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11717019/1576416 & http://ankitthakkar90.blogspot.in/2013/01/apk-expansion-files-in-android-with.html

Answer (score 0):

This answer maybe not a direct answer to your question, but still I would recommend you to upload your `mp3` file to a server and download or play them by demand.
This solution will make your content management more easy without updating the app itself.
Also you can consider to use mobile-web solution.