# Large sized 'offline' Android app

Tags: android, local-storage, offline, filesize, apk-expansion-files

I want to develop an Android app with my favorites videos and songs included for offline use. My interest is to keep the android app size smaller. But for now, I just know how to include videos and music on the `raw` folder. This way dramatically increases the app's size. Another solution found is [APK Expansion File](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/google/play/expansion-files.html) but I can't figure out how to create this file for offline instalation.
If you can provide some insights, I will appretiate it.

Comment: The app shouldn't contain the songs itself, the user should get them from a source and store them in the app's folder.

Comment: App with the songs 'itself' is a requirement. The only source will be the app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Steps to create APK expansion file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715855/steps-to-create-apk-expansion-file)

Comment: If you want your app to store large files locally, I'm not sure how you expect to keep the size down.

Comment: Why don't you store those file online and download them to local in the first use? It is simple without creating any expansion or put them in app folder.