# Android Expansion File using drawable

Tags: android, android-drawable, apk-expansion-files

I'm working on adding (Android Expansion File) to my project which includes more than 1000 images, which exist in the Drawable file, but I am currently stuck in implementing this within the Expansion File.

So far I'm done the following:

1. Download required packages and add it to my project.
2. Declaring user permissions at Manifest.
3. Implementing the downloader service and declared it in Manifest.
4. Implementing the alarm receiver and declared it in Manifest.

Now the problem is: I don't know how to handle the Expansion activity for Drawable images.

Answer (score 0):

It's already answered and the answer got 87 votes
so I think it will help you.[please click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715855/steps-to-create-apk-expansion-file)

Hope it helps.