# Android APK with pre-installed localized data

Tags: android, localization

We have an Android application that supports up to 5 languages. If we were to pre-install a set of data, we would normally add 5 zip files (1 for each language). However, the data has since grown to be 100Mb each. As such, its not possible to package all the 5 zips in the assets folder.

What options do we have to creating a APK with pre-installed data? Is it possible for users to install a extension pack based on their device locale? Or do we have to upload 5 APKs in the Play Store, one for each language.

Comment: you can do it on language selection by downloading language pack

Comment: @Anil, do you mean language selection in the Google Play Publish console?

Answer (score 0):

In documentation, it is given -

> Google Play currently requires that your APK file be no more than
>   100MB . If your app exceeded 100MB, you had to host and download the additional resources yourself when the user opens the app.

Read this about [APK Expansion Files](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html).

Also, In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14170038/5996106) answer, it is given how to make `.obb` file as `.zip` file and upload it on Play Store.

**OR**

You can also make a check on App opens / or ask the user to download the language pack and download it directly from the server .(That would be simpler and easier one).

Comment: We are trying to see if we can have an alternative to downloading it from the server so that the user downloads it while installing the app. Reason is that after installing, the user could turn off wifi, out application would the need the user to turn on wifi to download the data files. Expansion files does not also seem possible as we would have data_english.zip, data_french.zip, data_chinese.zip etc, language dependent data files, depending on the user's device Locale.

Comment: You can prompt user a message that there is one-time download of heavy file please keep wifi ON, else on mobile data, you will be charged more, Something like that.