# Android, load a large number of pictures in the android project

Tags: android, image, android-studio, drawable

I have to upload 200mb pictures in the android project (around 4000 pictures). I need it to have everything in local in the app. I tried to put everything in the drawable folder. But it doesn't install the application telling me:

> Unknown failure (at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:752))

When I click on Binder.java:752 it takes me to this line:

> checkParcel(this, code, reply, "Unreasonably large binder reply buffer");

So, I think, the problem is that I put everything in drawable. Does anyone have any clue about how can I figure out this riddle?

Comment: You shouldn't put so large image files in your drawable folder as it has a limited buffer size. My suggestion would be to store the images in a remote network like `Firebase` and have the URL to load Images in your project at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used it before but Google have a solution for big APK files, it's name APK expension files. Official document is here: https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files

Also you can found some explanation about expension files in this thread: [Steps to create APK expansion file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715855/steps-to-create-apk-expansion-file)

Alternatively, you can download image files into a directory for use. But users can be access images with file explorer application.